# Java Type Erasure and Overloading?

Tags: java, generics, spring-mvc, overloading, type-erasure

Can anyone explain in simple terms why in the below class, when I pass in a String, Integer or UUID, only the method overload taking Object as a parameter is used?

```
public final class SkuHydratingConverter implements Converter<Object, Sku> {
    @Autowired
    private SkuService skuService;


    /**
     * Default implementation, that errs as we don't know how to convert from
     * the source type.
     */
    public Sku convert(Object source) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not convert to Sku");
    }


    public Sku convert(String source) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        return convert(Integer.valueOf(source));
    }


    public Sku convert(Integer source) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        return skuService.get(source);
    }


    public Sku convert(UUID source) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        return skuService.get(source);
    }
}
```

Originally I'd wanted to implement `Converter<?, ?>` three times in the one class, but I soon discovered that's not possible.

Comment: How do you access this method? Can you give a code sample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overloading mechanism works in compile time, that is, which method to call is decided when compiling the classes, not when you run the program.

Since runtime types can't (in general) be known at compile time, a snippet like this

```
Object o = "some string";
method(o);
```

will result in a call to a `method` that takes an `Object` as argument, as `Object` is the [compile-time type](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexghi/archive/2009/05/20/compile-time-type-vs-runtime-type-of-a-variable.aspx) of `o`.

(This has nothing to do with type-erasure or generics.)

Answer (score 1):

Only method that you are actually implementing for Converter is convert(Object source), because you gave type-parameter Object in:

```
Converter<Object, Sku>
```

Two other convert-methods with String and UUID arguments you can call only when you use instance directly (not via interface). These two method do not override anything, they overload.

```
Converter con = new SkuHydratingConverter();
con.convert(new String());//calls convert(Object), it does not know about any other method

SkuHydratingConverter con2 = new SkuHydratingConverter();
con2.convert(new String()); //calls convert(String), because it is one with best matching type of argument.
```

Answer (score 0):

As others explained this is not related to erasure but the fact that `convert(Object source)` is bound at compile time. If you put an `@Override` before each you will get error in the rest, showing that only that method is overriding the super-class method.

What you need is runtime checking of actual type:

```
public Sku convert(Object source) throws IllegalArgumentException
{
    if (source instanceof String) {
        return convert((String) source);
    } else if (source instanceof ...) {
    } else // none match, source is of unknown type
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not convert to Sku, unsuported type " + source.getClass());
    }
}

}
```

The other `convert` methods should be `private`.