# Is it true that overloading must differ in parameter types or number of parameters but not erasure in Java?

Tags: java, overloading, type-erasure

[Erasure is decided at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5527267/7769052) and [overloaded method to call is resolved at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7511971/7769052).

Is it correct to say that overloading must differ in parameter types or number of parameters but not erasure in Java? Is it not equivalent in the context of overloading? If the methods differ in types or number of parameters, then their erasures differ as well every time? Is it incorrect to say that overloading must differ in the erasure just because it refers to runtime instead of compile time?

**EDIT**: For example, `foo(List<String>)` and `foo(List<Integer>)` have the same erasure and different parameter types, right? But [compiling them result in an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44939290/java-name-clash-error-a-method-has-the-same-erasure-as-another-method)

> java: name clash: `foo(java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>)` and `foo(java.util.List<java.lang.String>)` have the same erasure

So what is more important? Erasure or parameter type?

Comment: "Erasure is decided at runtime" - no, it's not. The erasure of a type is *known* at compile-time. The link you've provided is effectively saying that "at execution time, the type information *has been erased* from the object". In other words, if you just have a reference to an object, you can't tell the difference between a `List<String>` and a `List<Object>`.

Comment: @JonSkeet I didn't know that. I think it's good to include that in the answer

Comment: See [this section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9) of the JLS. `foo(List<String>)` and `foo(List<Integer>)` *are* "overloads" of `foo`, by the definitions. The fact that it doesn't compile is because of a rule specified [somewhere else](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3).

Comment: Also note that the code which the question in the first link claims to compile, doesn't actually compile. Something probably changed between Java versions.

Comment: @Sweeper - Correct.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7233730/139985 which states that it (erroneously) compiled without errors due to a bug in the `javac` compiler which was fixed in Java 7.

Comment: I combined your comments into an answer, thank you

Answer (score 2):

> Erasure is decided at runtime

No, it's not. The erasure of a type is known at compile-time. The link you've provided is effectively saying that "at execution time, the type information has been erased from the object". In other words, if you just have a reference to an object, you can't tell the difference between a `List<String>` and a `List<Integer>`.

[The overloading section of JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9):

> If two methods of a class (whether both declared in the same class, or both inherited by a class, or one declared and one inherited) have the same name but signatures that are not override-equivalent, then the method name is said to be overloaded.
>
> This fact causes no difficulty and never of itself results in a compile-time error.

[And signature is defined in another section of JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2):

> Two methods or constructors, M and N, have the same signature if they have the same name, the same type parameters (if any) (§8.4.4), and, after adapting the formal parameter types of N to the type parameters of M, the same formal parameter types.

So because method signature consists of the method name and parameter list, in case of overloads, overloads are methods of the same name with different formal parameter types.

`foo(List<String>)` and `foo(List<Integer>)` are overloads of `foo` by the above definitions. The fact that it doesn't compile is because of a rule specified [in another section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3).

In summary, it's not the erasure but the parameter list that defines whether the method is overloaded.

---

*Thank @Jon Skeet and @Sweeper for providing valuable comments and references. The answer is mostly a combination of their comments and the text from references*